# QGIS - WMS Service DEM (re)calculate height

Tags: qgis, dem

Is there a way to calculate the height, or recalculate the raster image, that was screenshoted from a WMS Service (DEM - digital elevation model) - f.e. the pixel-value is 118 but the height in that location is 75,6 Meters. Is there an easy approach?

[image]

Comment: I think that this is not possible. What you see in the image is a shaded relief. The pixels in the image are grey scale values that are derived from slope and aspect. There's no way to recreate elevation from this image.

Comment: A WMS doesn't give you the actual data, just an image representation; if you know the source data you might be able to get the WMS to supply a different  representation, by getting it to apply a different style that you supply using SLD or SLD_Body parameters.   I don't think though that QGIS has any inbuilt ability to create and append such a request parameter.